# Binding Input box to another div's CSS in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

Relative noob to Backbone here. This is the first time I am attempting to build an application with it.

I have 4 HTML divs containing input boxes. These input boxes are denoted by "topLeftOption", "topRightOption" etc in the optionsModel. Beside each input box is a div that I would like to show a preview of the colour the user typed in the box. Also, I wish to have the input value remain in the input box when the template re-renders. I am really having difficulty wrapping my head around this. See code below:

**HTML Template**

```
            <div>
                <label class="optionsLabel">Size:</label>
                    <select id="gridSize" class="form-control">
                        <option value="3x3">3x3</option>
                        <option value="4x4">4x4</option>
                    </select>
                <br>

                <label class="optionsLabel">Insert Colour Hex Codes: </label>
                    <div id="hexOptions" class="input-group">
                        <span id="topLeftPreview" class="hexOptionsPreview"></span>
                        <input id="topLeftOption" type="text" class="form-control gridOption" placeholder="Top Left" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">


                        <input id="topRightOption" type="text" class="form-control gridOption" placeholder="Top Right" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <span id="topRightPreview" class="hexOptionsPreview"></span>

                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <span id="bottomLeftPreview" class="hexOptionsPreview"></span>
                        <input id="bottomLeftOption" type="text" class="form-control gridOption" placeholder="Bottom Left" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">

                        <input id="bottomRightOption" type="text" class="form-control gridOption" placeholder="Bottom Right" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <span id="bottomRightPreview" class="hexOptionsPreview"></span>
                    </div>
                <div>
                    <button id="generateGrid">Generate Grid</button>
                </div>

            </div>
</script>
```

**Model Definition**

```
var app = app || {};

app.optionsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults: {

    size: "",
    topLeftOption: {
        value: "",
        link: $("#topLeftPreview")
    },
    topRightOption: {
        value: "",
        link: $("#topRightPreview")
    },
    bottomLeftOption: {
        value: "",
        link: $("#bottomLeftPreview")

    },
    bottomRightOption: {
        value: "",
        link: $("#bottomRightPreview")
    }

},

changeCSS: function(colour, id) {
    //was playing with stuff here
},

changeValue: function(e) {
    var colour = $(e.currentTarget).val()
    var id = e.currentTarget.id;
    console.log(colour);
    console.log(id);
    this.set(id.toString(), colour);
}
});
```

**View Definition**

```
var app = app || {};

app.optionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: "#optionsContainer",
template: _.template($("#optionsTemplate").html()),
initialize: function(options) {
    this.render();
    this.model.on("change", this.render, this)

},

events: {
    "change input.gridOption": "contentChanged"
},

contentChanged: function(e) {
    this.model.changeValue(e);
    var x = this.model.changedAttributes();

},

render: function(e) {

    this.$el.html(this.template());
}
})
```

**CSS**

```
#optionsContainer {
width:20em;

background-color:#F3F9FF;
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

.optionsLabel {
padding:.4em;
}

.gridOption {
width:41% !important;
}

#hexOptions {
margin-left:1.5em;


}

.hexOptionsPreview {
float:left;
width:1em;
height:1em;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color:#245269;
}
```

**Model/View Instance**

```
var gridSize = $('#gridSize :selected').val();

var optionsM = new app.optionsModel();


var optionsV = new app.optionsView({
model: optionsM
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring this out. Used the "changeValue" function to edit the model by passing it a reference to the affected div from the view change event. Therefore, the model was being kept up to date with the correct values. I then used the following code in the View's render function to update the corresponding preview divs.

```
render: function() {
    console.log(this.model.toJSON());

    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    $('#topLeftPreview').css("background-color",    
this.model.get('topLeftOption'));
    $('#topRightPreview').css("background-color",   
this.model.get('topRightOption'));
    $('#bottomLeftPreview').css("background-color", 
this.model.get('bottomLeftOption'));
    $('#bottomRightPreview').css("background-color",       
this.model.get('bottomRightOption'));

    $('#topLeftOption').val(this.model.get('topLeftOption'));
    $('#topRightOption').val(this.model.get('topRightOption'));
    $('#bottomLeftOption').val(this.model.get('bottomLeftOption'));
    $('#bottomRightOption').val(this.model.get('bottomRightOption'));



}
```